# Changes to build.sbt to enable ScalaTest tests to run with Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, intellij-13

I am following the docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest), and this does not seem to work at all; but I'm not even sure what am I doing wrong here.

For a start, just adding the given snippet in a `project/Build.scala` file causes a compile error; so that's a non-start.
Wrapping it inside an object which extends `Build` (as in the SBT example) does not cause a compile error, but the tests are not run.

Eventually, I've added the following to my `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.0.0" % "test",
    ...
```

this is marginally better, but in IntelliJ, my `ApplicationSpec` has all sorts of compilation error:

```
import org.scalatestplus.play._

import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

class ApplicationSpec extends PlaySpec {

  "A Stack" must {
    "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
      val stack = new Stack[Int]
      stack.push(1)
      stack.push(2)
      stack.pop() mustBe 2
      stack.pop() mustBe 1
    }
    "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
      val emptyStack = new Stack[Int]
      a [NoSuchElementException] must be thrownBy {
        emptyStack.pop()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`must`, `mustBe` and `a` are not recognized.
Finally, if I try to run `activator test` I get:

```
sentinel/test:definedTests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.specs2.runner.Fingerprints$.fp1()Lorg/specs2/runner/SpecificationFingerprint;
    at org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework.fingerprints(SbtRunner.scala:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sbt.TestFramework$.getFingerprints(TestFramework.scala:113)
    at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$discover$1.apply(Tests.scala:242)
    at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$discover$1.apply(Tests.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Tests$.discover(Tests.scala:242)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$detectTests$1.apply(Defaults.scala:556)
    ...
[error] (sentinel/test:definedTests) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Essentially, an epic fail - it would be great if the docs were a bit more specific in what is required and what is expected for all the machinery to work: as things stand, it's kinda difficult to untangle the mess.

I've been googling and looking here on stack overflow for hours today, looked at the ScalaTestPlus docs (well, the whole two paragraphs of it...) and tried many variations, all to no avail.

The [full project's code is on github](https://github.com/massenz/sentinel).

Worth noting that if I give in to the "power-of-bad-documentation" and I use Specs2, then tests run correctly (at least from inside Intellij, and as far as the 'hello world' example goes).

I would still much prefer to using ScalaTest (can't really see why I need to learn TWO testing frameworks, really) - so, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could your IntelliJ IDEA be out of sync with the build.sbt file? If you didn't select the "auto import" checkbox when you imported the project into IntelliJ, you'll need to manually import it. The first experiment I'd ask you to try to find out is to just try and run the tests manually outside of IntelliJ. If they run fine there, then I'd reimport the project into IntelliJ.

Comment: @BillVenners that's definitely not the case, changes in build.sbt are reflected immediately in the run. In any event, even running from activator causes the tests to fail with the latter exception.

Comment: OK. We'll try it from your project. The stack trace you are getting is not coming from ScalaTest, so something else is amiss.

Comment: Thanks @BillVenners - the branch is here: https://github.com/massenz/sentinel/tree/79330610_API_unit_tests feel free to pull and mess around with it.  I found a thread in the user group that mentioned this: `testOptions in Test := Nil` to be added somewhere (I'm guessing inside Build.scala?) do you know anything about it? Thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/rZBfNoGtC0M

Comment: Interesting issue - read it entirely. However, would you consider renaming the title since it kind of gives a dim idea about using ScalaTest with Play. Maybe not fully deserved (somewhat though)? :)

Comment: Changed the title, hopefully it reflects better the topic.  TBH, this thread is so old (1 year ago) that I'm not even sure it still applies; having said that, my ScalaTest tests still run happily with Play, so I must be doing something right ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, it turned out it was indeed a library version mismatch, but one I hadn't anticipated.

It revolves around the fact that I have a sub-project in my sbt build, which works just fine, but was importing ScalaTest 2.2.1, while I was using 2.1.7 to make it work with ScalaTest+ 1.1.0 - however, using ScalaTest 2.1.7 (which, indeed works with ST+ 1.1.0) only for the 'top-level' project was causing the weirdness around the abstract class, etc.

The [Versions, Versions, Versions](http://scalatest.org/plus/play/versions) page has now been updated by Bill, and the fix has been to use ScalaTest 2.2.1, ScalaTestPlus 1.2.0 and Play 2.3.0 - which all play nice together.

*Updated* - the above still caused tests to fail via `sbt/activator test`, I could only run the tests via IntelliJ: the fix has been to update the build.sbt to use Scala 2.11

In the end, to make this work, this is what I have in my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "sentinel"

version := "0.2-SNAPSHOT"

organization := "AlertAvert.com"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-language:postfixOps")

// The REST project depends on Core Sentinel classes
lazy val sentinel_core = project

lazy val sentinel = (project in file("."))
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
    .aggregate(sentinel_core)
    .dependsOn(sentinel_core)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.2.0" % "test",
  cache
)
```

(I'm reproducing it in its entirety, so that if someone else has the same problem, they'll see it - it infuriates me when people only paste a fragment and some key essentials are omitted :)

Major credits to Bill Venners for the help and guidance.

Comment: Had the same issues with current versions:  `playframework 2.5.12`, `scalatest 3.0.1`, `scalatestplus-play 1.5.1`. A change of `scalatestplus-play 2.0.0` fixed the issue instaranntaneously.

This saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Appears you have library version mismatch somewhere.

I have been using Scalatest with Play and haven't had any issues.

I am using Play 2.3.4, ScalaTest 2.2.1.

```
 activator "test-only com.abc.tests.controllers.ApplicationSpec"

[info] ApplicationSpec:
[info] A Stack
[info] - must pop values in last-in-first-out order
[info] - must throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 1 second, 119 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

Comment: That's definitely true - I just realized that if run this from activator: `test-only ActivationSpec` it still tries to run them via Specs2 (while it should instead run ScalaTest).  But I don't know where the 'version mismatch' comes from!

Comment: could you please share your `build.sbt` and the contents of your project/ sub-directory?